# Displaying joined fields in Flask-Admin ModelView

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-admin

I have a Flask app using Flask-SQLAlchemy with some simple relational data mapping, e.g. between *Orders* and *OrderItems* belonging to those orders.

In my Flask-Admin backend I would like to show *some* of the order attributes in the list of *OrderItems* — as opposed to having the entire order object. E.g. make the "Order.email" listed (can be read-only) in the *OrderItems*' rows.

I've looked into the `inline_models` attribute of the ModelView, but this seems to be more feared towards actually editing the relational object — I just want to display (and sort/search by) some value of the "parent".

Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily include fields via a foreign key relationship by including them in `column_list` value - [documentation](https://flask-admin.readthedocs.io/en/v1.0.6/api/mod_model/#flask.ext.admin.model.BaseModelView.column_list). Consider the two simplified models, note the `company` back reference in the `Address` model:

```
class Company(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'companies'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.Unicode(255), nullable=False, unique=True, index=True)
    website = db.Column(db.Unicode(255), nullable=True)
    notes = db.Column(db.UnicodeText())

    @hybrid_property
    def address_count(self):
        return len(self.addresses)

    @address_count.expression
    def address_count(cls):
        return select([func.count(Address.id)]).where(Address.company_id == cls.id).label("address_count")


    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Address(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'addresses'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    address1 = db.Column(db.Unicode(255), nullable=False)
    town = db.Column(db.Unicode(255), index=True, nullable=False)
    county = db.Column(db.Unicode(255))
    country = db.Column(db.Unicode(255))
    post_code = db.Column(db.Unicode(10))

    company_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('companies.id'), index=True)
    company = db.relationship(Company, backref=db.backref('addresses', uselist=True, lazy='select', cascade='delete-orphan,all'))


    def __str__(self):
        return ', '.join(filter(None, [self.address1, self.town, self.county, self.post_code, self.country]))
```

In the Address view you can access a "parent" company using dotted notation. For example:

```
class AddressView(ModelAdmin):

    column_list = (
        'company.name',
        'company.website',
        'address1',
        'address2'
        )
```

Comment: The elegance of things in the Flask domain is still sometimes baffling... hadn't even occurred to me it could be that easy :)

Comment: @pjcunningham, how do you make the company.website column searchable? I can't get this to work in flask-admin. Adding it to searchable_columns gives the following exception: Invalid field company.website does not contains any columns.

Comment: Unfortunately, if you write it this way, it will make N additional requests to db. For each address row, it will make an additional request to fetch the company for this address. To use join here, you need to rewrite get_query and get_count_query methods.